# How do you detect active Dialog in On MessageActivityAsync

Tags: c#, botframework

I have created a DispatchBot using Luis and QnA and I want to additionally use multiple Dialogs (one for each intent.

Everything is working except if the dialog needs to prompt for a question. If you get the all the entities in the first utterance you can respond and all is good, however if you need to request further info that is when it fails. When the user responds it goes back to OnMessageActivityAsync and then forgets about the dialog.

I understand that I need to run RunAsync(..) to reopen the dialog however I can't get the right context.  Everything I have tried either opens the dialog with null Accessors/DialogState or fails to open the dialog.

I am very new to Azure Bot Framework and I have spent days googling but each example doesn't do everything I need to do.

My bot is as follows:

```
   public class DispatchBot : ActivityHandler
    {
        private readonly ILogger<DispatchBot> _logger;
        private readonly IBotServices _botServices;
        private readonly DialogSet _dialogSet;
        private readonly MilaAccessors _milaAccessors;
        private readonly BotState _userState;

        public DispatchBot(IBotServices botServices, ILogger<DispatchBot> logger, MilaAccessors accessors)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _botServices = botServices;
            _dialogSet = new DialogSet(accessors.ConversationDialogState);
            _milaAccessors = accessors;
            _userState = accessors.UserState;

        }

        protected override async Task OnMessageActivityAsync(ITurnContext<IMessageActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            await base.OnMessageActivityAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken);
            await _milaAccessors.ConversationState.SaveChangesAsync(turnContext, false, cancellationToken);

            List<Dialog> dialogs = _dialogSet.GetDialogs().ToList();


            if (dialogs.Any()) //This is always false
            {
                //If count is greater than zero, then you can continue dialog conversation.  
                await dialogs.First().RunAsync(turnContext, _milaAccessors.ConversationState.CreateProperty<DialogState>(nameof(DialogState)), cancellationToken);
            }
            else
            {
                // First, we use the dispatch model to determine which cognitive service (LUIS or QnA) to use.
                var recognizerResult = await _botServices.Dispatch.RecognizeAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken);

                // Top intent tell us which cognitive service to use.
                var topIntent = recognizerResult.GetTopScoringIntent();

                // Next, we call the dispatcher with the top intent.
                if (topIntent.score > 0.5)
                {
                    await DispatchToTopIntentAsync(turnContext, topIntent.intent, recognizerResult, cancellationToken);
                }
                else
                {
                    await ProcessQnAAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken);
                }
            }



        }

        private async Task DispatchToTopIntentAsync(ITurnContext<IMessageActivity> turnContext, string intent, RecognizerResult recognizerResult, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            switch (intent)
            {
                case "Form15":
                    await Form15IntentAsync(turnContext, recognizerResult.Properties["luisResult"] as LuisResult, cancellationToken);
                    break;
                case "Layouts":
                    await ProcessLayoutsAsync(turnContext, recognizerResult.Properties["luisResult"] as LuisResult, cancellationToken);
                    break;
                case "Weather":
                    await ProcessWeatherAsync(turnContext, recognizerResult.Properties["luisResult"] as LuisResult, cancellationToken);
                    break;
                default:
                    await ProcessQnAAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken);
                    break;
            }
        }
}
```

And the Dialogs are of the form:

```
public class Form15Dialog : ComponentDialog
{
    private const string UserInfo = "form15-userInfo";
    private readonly MilaAccessors _milaAccessors;
    private readonly string DlgAddressId = "AddressDlg";
    private readonly string Form15Id = "Form15DialogName";
    private readonly BotState _userState;
    private readonly BotState _conversationState;


    public Form15Dialog(MilaAccessors milaAccessors) : base(nameof(Form15Dialog))
    {
        _milaAccessors = milaAccessors;
        _userState = milaAccessors.UserState;
        _conversationState = milaAccessors.ConversationState;


        AddDialog(new TextPrompt(DlgAddressId, AddressValidation));
        AddDialog(new WaterfallDialog(nameof(Form15Id), new WaterfallStep[]
        {
            InitialiseStepAsync,
            GetAddressStepAsync,
            DisplayForm15StepAsync
        }));

        InitialDialogId = nameof(Form15Id);

    }

    private async Task<DialogTurnResult> InitialiseStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        stepContext.Values["MilaAccessors"] = _milaAccessors;
        UserProfile userProfile = _milaAccessors.UserProfile.GetAsync(stepContext.Context, () => new UserProfile(), cancellationToken).Result;

        Form15DialogValues userInfo = new Form15DialogValues {Name = userProfile.Name, MilaSessionId = userProfile.SessionId};

        IList<EntityModel> options = (IList<EntityModel>)stepContext.Options;
        foreach (EntityModel model in options)
        {
            switch (model.Type)
            {
                case "JobNumber":
                    userInfo.JobNumber = model.Entity;
                    break;
                case "Sections":
                    userInfo.Sections = model.Entity;
                    break;
                case "StreetAddress":
                    userInfo.StreetAddress = model.Entity;
                    break;
                case "Suburb":
                    userInfo.Suburb = model.Entity;
                    break;
                case "PostCode":
                    userInfo.PostCode = model.Entity;
                    break;
            }

        }

        // Create an object in which to collect the user's information within the dialog.
        stepContext.Values[UserInfo] = userInfo;

        if (UpdateUserInfoFromWebService(userInfo))
        {
            stepContext.Values[UserInfo] = userInfo;
            return await stepContext.NextAsync(new List<string>(), cancellationToken);
        }


        await _userState.SaveChangesAsync(stepContext.Context, false, cancellationToken);
        await _conversationState.SaveChangesAsync(stepContext.Context, false, cancellationToken);


        PromptOptions promptOptions = new PromptOptions { Prompt = MessageFactory.Text("Could you give me the full Job Address?") };
        return await stepContext.PromptAsync(DlgAddressId, promptOptions, cancellationToken);
    }


    private async Task<DialogTurnResult> GetAddressStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {

        Form15DialogValues userInfo = (Form15DialogValues)stepContext.Values[UserInfo];

        if (!(stepContext.Result is string[] results) || results.Length == 0)
        {
            return await stepContext.NextAsync(new List<string>(), cancellationToken);
        }

        userInfo.JobNumber = null;
        userInfo.StreetAddress = results[0];
        userInfo.Suburb = null;

        if (UpdateUserInfoFromWebService(userInfo))
        {
            stepContext.Values[UserInfo] = userInfo;
            return await stepContext.NextAsync(new List<string>(), cancellationToken);
        }


        await _userState.SaveChangesAsync(stepContext.Context, false, cancellationToken);
        await _conversationState.SaveChangesAsync(stepContext.Context, false, cancellationToken);

        var promptOptions = new PromptOptions { Prompt = MessageFactory.Text("I'm unable to find that address.  Could you please enter the job number?") };
        return await stepContext.PromptAsync(nameof(TextPrompt), promptOptions, cancellationToken);

    }
```

I have been following the info in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-dialog-manage-conversation-flow?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp however I can not get "Dialog.RunAsync".

Any help/links/pointers you could give me would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can inject an instance of your dialog into the bot constructor like below

```
private readonly BotState _userState;
private readonly Dialog Dialog;

            public DispatchBot(IBotServices botServices, ILogger<DispatchBot> logger, MilaAccessors accessors,Form15Dialog  dialog)
            {
                _logger = logger;
                _botServices = botServices;
                _dialogSet = new DialogSet(accessors.ConversationDialogState);
                _milaAccessors = accessors;
                _userState = accessors.UserState;
                 Dialog  = dialog;
            }
```

Now you can run the below code in OnMessageActivityAsync to continue with your previous dialog

```
await Dialog.RunAsync(turnContext, ConversationState.CreateProperty<DialogState>(nameof(DialogState)), cancellationToken);
```

Comment: Thank-you very much - huge help.

Comment: @RobP , if this had helper , please make sure to mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you never call `stepContext.EndDialogAsync` WaterfallStep always finishes with the end of the Waterfall. In your code, it's `DisplayForm15StepAsync` and your dialog will be finished and goes back to `OnMessageActivityAsync`

So no need to reopen the active dialog, you should re-prompt at your WaterfallStep when it fails and doesn't let it finish until you get the right context